# Pandas DataFrame: Manipulate value in one column based von value in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two Pandas DataFrames df and df_0:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition': [1, 2, 3], 
                     'value': [1, 2, 3]})
df_0 = pd.DataFrame({'condition': [1, 2], 
                     'value': [1, 3]})
   condition  value
0          1      1
1          2      2
1          3      3
   condition  value
0          1      1
1          2      3
```

I want to subtract (-=) the value in df_0 from the value (column) in df, if the resp. condition value/column is the same.

```
Pseudo code 
df_desired_result = pd.DataFrame({'condition': [1, 2, 3], 
                     'value': [0, -1, 3]})

   condition  value
0          1      0
1          2     -1
2          3      3
```

How can I achiev this?

Thanks a lot in advance for your reply!

Lucy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pandas does an index wise arithmetic operations.
just set the 'condition' to be the index, and then fill the NaN values

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition': [1, 2, 3], 
                     'value': [1, 2, 3]})
df_0 = pd.DataFrame({'condition': [1, 2], 
                     'value': [1, 3]})
df_desired_result  = df.set_index('condition')-df_0.set_index('condition').reindex(df.condition,fill_value=0)
print(df_desired_result)
```

Comment: What if there were more condition columns, let's'call them condition1 and condition2, which both need to have the same value resp. for the subtractin to take place, e. g. subtract values if condition1 == condition1_0 and condition2 == condition2_0? Regards! Lucy

Comment: you can do df.set_index(['condition1','condition2'])